# Twitter / Facebook Share dynamic URL

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, hyperlink, share

I am trying to create a custom share link so on click it will share the current URL.
I understand this

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=An%20Awesome%20Link&url=http://www.google.com">
Share This on Twitter</a>
```

But is there any way to make it dynamic, so it will grab the URL of the page the user is on and share that, rather than a hard coded link.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript you can use :

```
document.URL
```

It gives you the current url

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.URL

and

```
document.title
```

for getting the title of this page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.title

with jQuery or javascript you can set the href attribute

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/stylesheet/href

Example:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('href', 
        'http://twitter.com/share?text='+document.title+'&url=' + document.URL);
});
```

Another way:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions, Joan yours works but it is directing to this http://twitter.com/share?text=HNIB%20|%20Tim%20Bret%20Day&url=http://tbd.aaronnicholls.co.uk/work/hnib/

Comment: I think the spaces in the Document Title are adding %20%

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    document.location = 'http://twitter.com/share?text=' + document.title + '&url=' + window.location.href;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<a data-count='horizontal' expr:href='data:post.canonicalUrl' href='http://twitter.com/share' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>Share on twitter</a>
```

Putting  `expr:href='data:post.canonicalUrl'`  does the trick.

nonetheless,twiiter gives you an option while [generating buttons](https://web.archive.org/web/20131104183617/https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet)
[image]
<sub>(source: [ctrlv.in](https://img.ctrlv.in/img/51530000c7bdc.png))</sub>